# Is there anyway to find out number of threads are using the object currently ?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Basically I want to find out how many threads are using the object currently. 
If nobody is using this object reference, then I want to destroy this object.

Example

```
 User u = new User();
 (here I have other code) 
 if (u is not used by any thread) {
   u = null;
 }
```

Comment: What does "threat T uses object O" even mean? Are you perchance trying to re-invent garbage collection?

Comment: What prevents you from setting the object to `null` without regard to the threads using it? They would continue using it until they are done, and then the object would get GC-ed the normal way.

Comment: I think the confusion lies in the words "destroy this object". Setting the reference to null does not destroy anything. It just eliminates one reason for the object to continue to exist. The garbage collector will wait until the object is unreachable by any thread to destroy it.

Comment: Voted to reopen.  While this question is misguided, it is clear what the OP is asking, and it is clearly answerable ... by explaining the misconceptions in the Question.  And a good Answer would be useful to others with similar misconceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This Question is based on a *fundamental misunderstanding* of Java memory management.

Assigning `null` to a variable does **NOT** destroy the object it previously referred to.  What it *actually* does is to break one of possibly many paths (chains of references from live variables) to the object that make it "reachable".  When no more paths exist, the object cannot be reached (used) by anything in the program and is *eligible* to be garbage collected.  When it actually goes away is at the discretion of the JVM / garbage collector.

You are trying to make the `User` object "go away" when nothing else has its reference.  But that is going to happen anyway.  All you really need to do is to unconditionally assign `null` to `u` so that *this* variable doesn't stop the User object going away.

Can you make the `User` object go away "now"?  Well the answer is complicated, by it boils down to:

- you can't do it reliably, and
- you can't do it efficiently.

---

And to answer the question in the question title.

> Is there anyway to find out number of threads are using the object currently ?

No.  Not in the sense that you mean.  The JVM doesn't even provide a way to find out how many live copies of the Object's reference there are.  The closest that the JVM comes to providing this are the `SoftReference` and `WeakReference` classes that can be used to detect that an object no longer has any normal (strong) references to it.

But this is not necessary for solving your "problem".

Comment: Tangential to the matter at hand, but I'd recommend a ```PhantomReference``` for determining when an object has been garbage-collected, as opposed to a ```WeakReference```. The latter would imply that you are yourself using the object until it expires, while the former implies you only need to know that it has expired.